# How do I Static Pages to routes.rb file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a few static pages, do I need to add one by one? os is there a hack that allows me to add all static pages at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use high_voltage.  It's a gem that helps you manage static pages.

It's dead simple.

Add the gem

```
gem 'high_voltage'
```

Create the pages directory (it's called pages by default)

```
mkdir app/views/pages
```

Add all your pages inside that directory with the same name you want the url to be.  For instance for your about page, create a file called `app/views/pages/about.html.erb` -- then

Add links to any pages

```
= link_to 'About Us', page_path('about')
```

and the url will be

```
/pages/about
```

Comment: This is gold and it worked perfect :) Thank you so much.

Comment: Not a problem :) To help the next guy that comes along consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds naive, but what is wrong with putting the files in the public folder if they are truly static (i.e, not erb) - what value does high_voltage add in that case?

Comment: Nothing stops you from doing that at all.  Assuming they need need zero assets (images, css files, or javascripts) that are part of the asset pipeline and as such won't resolve the same way in development as in production.  If they are genuinely static and need no rails-based resources there's no problem at all.. its not very rails-y, but that's a matter of convention, not performance or function.  There are some other things that it might affect, such as if you use gems for sitemap generation they would miss those bits, others editing your code might not be able to find those resources, etc